# What information can be gleamed by using a OTP twice with the same message?

Tags: encryption, cryptanalysis

So...

C0 = K0 ⊕ M and C1 = K1 ⊕ M where K0, K1 are different random numbers. What information can you discern about the K0, K1 and M, if any? Could you use K0,K1 again with another different message securely?

Comment: There are a lot of questions on this site about one-time pads and two-time pads.  Have you tried searching through them?  What have you found, and where have you got stuck?

Answer (score 2):

The OTP keys must be generated unpredictable from previously known bits.

If one knows that a message $M$ is encrypted twice with different key bits, the x-or will give out the $K_1 \oplus K_2$, nothing more.